# Text of View doesn't align vertically in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I am new in React Native. I am trying to understand how flexbox works in RN. Given my App component, I want to put the text in the center (both vertically and both horizontally).

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Colors from './src/assets/Colors';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    Text,
    StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showSplashScreen: true,
        };
    }

    render() {
        let showSplashScreen = this.state.showSplashScreen;
        return (
            <View style={styles.appBackground}>
                <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
                    {showSplashScreen && (<SplashScreen/>)}
                </SafeAreaView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class SplashScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View styles={{flex:1, backgroundColor: '#954876'}}>
                <Text style={styles.splashScreenText}>Hello World!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    appBackground: {
        height: '100%',
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.customerGreen,
    },
    splashScreenText: {
        color: Colors.white,
        textAlign: 'center',
        textAlignVertical: 'bottom',
    },
});

export default App;
```

But what I get is:

[image]

I have not clear at all why my flex doesn't stretch vertically, it should be automatic, or not?

Comment: AFAIK `textAlignVertical` is only applicable to android, not to iOS. Have you tried `alignSelf` and `justifyContent` ?

Comment: Sorry, I posted wrong code. Now you can see updated code. Yes, I have already tried to use justifyContent and alignItems.

Comment: Have you debugged to see if the `Text` parent (`View`)  is using all screen height?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
class SplashScreen extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View styles={{flex:1, backgroundColor: '#954876', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Text style={styles.splashScreenText}>Hello World!</Text>
        </View>
    );}}
```